# Does Gatling allow to simulate users on different computers?

Tags: scala, gatling

hi i am new to `Gatling` and i want to ask that with `JMeter`, a competing load testing platform , one can not only simulate users on the same computer but then you are testing your computers network and local system as well so `JMeter` allows you to run tasks from different computers and have them controlled through a central computer to simulate users accessing the site from different computers

Does gatling allow for the same ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [link](http://gatling.io/docs/2.1.7/cookbook/scaling_out.html) there is no cluster mode yet. It does explain how you would go about implementing something similar though.

Answer (score 2):

This is not supported yet and will probably be part of a commercial product as per :

- https://github.com/gatling/gatling/issues/415

Last comment:

> Done in commercial product

A workaround is to do it this way:

- http://gatling.io/docs/2.1.7/cookbook/scaling_out.html